# iOS Bundle ID is already taken when creating a LinkedIn app

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

I am trying to implement a "Login via LinkedIn" function to my iOS app through the LinkedIn SDK, but when I try to register my iOS App Bundle Identifier, I get an error saying that my App Identifier must be unique. It seems that another app is using my bundle identifier.

Is there a way to know this? And to set my bundle identifier (which I cannot change because the iOS app is already submitted to the App Store) to my LinkedIn app?

Thank you in advance

Comment: So may you do't have any apps with that bundle identifier but may be someone else using the same and as per the guidelines bundle identifier must be unique globally, not only within your own apps, and also there is no way to check the bundle identifier of others apps, only you can check yours own.

Comment: where are you seeing this error?  in LinkedIn or in iTunes connect?

Comment: @BuntyMadan, I know that is what's happening, but the problem is that everything worked fine two days ago, but since yesterday, the bundle identifier was de-registered from the LinkedIn and I can't set it back. Moreover, I'm using reverse-DNS to create the Bundle ID, so it should not already be taken

Comment: @michael-dautermann, The error is in LinkedIn